# Context is not available during NextJS partial render

Tags: next.js, material-ui, next.js13

I've recently migrated to NextJS app router and I started getting this error from Material-UI.

```
Error: MUI: `useColorScheme` must be called under <CssVarsProvider />
```

It [happens](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/ee8b09e68ec30421bca345500ae5c314027b59f9/packages/mui-system/src/cssVars/createCssVarsProvider.js#L54) if one uses `useColorScheme` outside of `<CssVarsProvider />`.

The thing is, I'm not sure how is it possible because my `layout.tsx` declares `<CssVarsProvider />` for every page.

```js
export default async function Layout() {
    return (
        <html>
        <body>
        <ThemeProvider>
            <UsesColorSchemeHook />
        </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

*Code is simplified*. Component `<ThemeProvider>` is a client component (ie. starts with 'use client') and it initialises `<CssVarsProvider>` inside.

```js
'use client';
// ...
export default function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
    // ...

    return (
        <CacheProvider value={cache}>
            <CssVarsProvider theme={theme} modeStorageKey="color_mode">
                <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
                {children}
            </CssVarsProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
    );
}
```

Component `<UsesColorSchemeHook>` calls `useColorScheme` and causes the error.

```js
'use client';
// ...
export default function UsesColorSchemeHook({ children }) {
    const { mode } = useColorScheme();

    return <div>{mode}</div>;
};
```

My guess is that NextJS 13 tries to render `<UsesColorSchemeHook />` partially, without initialising ThemeProvider and CssVarsProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark every component that uses useColorScheme with **'use client'**

But if you still need it to statically render, then you should divide your components and cut **client** parts into smaller sub components

Comment: Yep, component `UsesColorSchemeHook` has `use client`, because it uses hook.